# How hide menuItem in Shiny dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a menuItem in shiny dashboard:

menuItem("XXXYYY", tabName = "XXX", icon = icon("brain").

I would like to hide this menuItem and all menuSubItem when run my App. I'm a recent user on Shiny and I'm having trouble.